# Custom share permission to users in a samba file server

Tags: permissions, samba

I have a shared folder in samba in Ubuntu 12.04 lts desktop,
want to assign read only permission to 20 users and read-write permission to a single user, how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple guide for samba server:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide#File_Sharing_.28Advanced.29